# How to resize text for mobile devices (Css)

Tags: css, wordpress

Currently having issues scaling the text down to a mobile size, as the current parallax image has a text element on top of it and half the text is off screen when browser is resized or on a mobile device. I can move the text around, but struggling to resize it to fit on a mobile screen.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.vc_custom_1528382333513 {
font-size: 1% !important;
margin-left: -300px !important;
```

(.vc_custom is the element name)

Page in question- https://www.xordium.co.uk/your-cloud-journey/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can New fonts properties are there please see the link below
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your css rule is not applied to the text in the header. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H02aW.jpg). Try to select directly the span:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.vc_custom_1528382333513 span {
font-size:...
```

Or any other method.

Next, you should use **Viewport Sized Typography** for better and more accurate reponsivity. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.vc_custom_1528382333513 span {
font-size:6vw;
...
```

The result should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoAe9.jpg).

Not the best look, I know, but try some other numbers until you find something that fits correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using other units. eg viewport width.
Try setting the text to eg. `calc(16px + 2vw);`
Play around with the pixels or viewport width values until you find a solution that scales however you'd like.
check this CSS Tricks article [Fun with Viewport Units.](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) 
Also check out the CSS calc function. Its quite useful [A Couple of Use Cases for Calc()](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)